# how to add variable to array list and then total all the elements of arraylist?

Tags: java

I'm trying to input a variable into an ArrayList and then add all the elements. How can i do that? The code I tried is below.  Thanks.

```
ArrayList<String> aListNumbers = new ArrayList<String>();
int abc = 23;
aListNumbers.add("abc");
aListNumbers.add("2");
aListNumbers.add("3");

//Java ArrayList Sum All Elements

int sum = 0;
for(int i=0; i < aListNumbers.size(); i++){
    sum = sum + Integer.parseInt(aListNumbers.get(i));
}

System.out.println("Sum of all elements of ArrayList is " + sum);
```

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: What are you expecting the answer to be?  What are you currently getting?

Comment: guys this thing works if all the elements are passed like a string, but wont work like this, i have a different situation in my project where i want to pass a variable into the arraylist and get the total, so was trying this snippet separately.

Answer (score 7):

`aListNumbers.add("abc");`

Here you aren't adding the contents of the variable named `abc` to the list. You're adding the String "abc" to the list. This will cause a `NumberFormatException` when the code tries to parse the character string "abc" into a number - because "abc" just isn't a number.

`aListNumbers.add(abc);`

That's closer to what you want, but it will still complain because the variable `abc` isn't a String. Since `aListNumbers` expects Strings (as it is an `ArrayList<String>`), trying to add anything else will upset the compiler.

`aListNumbers.add(Integer.toString(abc));`

Will work.

Answer (score -1):

Use an ArrayList<Integer>  instead of String?